# Camera and Camera roll file format

Tags: ios, swift, png, jpeg

I'm working on the app which lets user to get an image from iPhone/iPad camera or camera roll, now I only process PNG images using following:

```
let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.imageView.image!);
```

My question is do I need to worry about JPEG images and implement UIImageJPEGRepresentation or there's no possibility of JPEGs incoming from camera roll/camera?

Comment: `UIImage` hides whatever the original format was. It doesn't matter if the original image was JPG, PNG, or anything else.

Comment: Be aware that PNG files don't store the image orientation. Better to use JPEG at maximum quality